# How to use LINQ to query matching items to a list?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, list

I would like query items in a list that match certain values, if I use something like,

```
var someList = someDbContext.Items.ToList();

var fullList = (from item in someList
                where item.Name == data.Name 
                & item.Job == data.Job
                select item).ToList();
```

Say `someList` contains Names and Jobs, like,

- John, Technician
- Rachel, System Adminstrator
- Frank, IT Support

Now if John, Technician intialize  as follows:

```
data.Name = "John";
data.Job = "Technician";
```

This should add this item to the list correct? However, for some reason they are not and the when I do,

```
var total = fullList.Count;
```

`total` equals 0.

Am I missing something? Why is **John, Technician** not be added to the list?

Here is more concrete coding example,

```
 Data data = new Data();
 Models.DataModel someDBContext = new Models.DataModel();

 data.Name = "John";
 data.Job = "Technician";

 var someList = someDbContext.Items.ToList();

 var fullList = (from item in someList
                    where item.Name == data.Name 
                    & item.Job == data.Job
                    select item).ToList();
```

Comment: Question seems a bit unclear. Please consider rephrasing it, and also taking care to provide examples which people could compile and test for themselves while trying to solve the problem.

Comment: What are the types of those fields?  strings?  Can we get object definitions?

Comment: You should use `&&` instead of `&`. First one is logical AND operator. Second is bitwise operator

Comment: The types are strings.

Comment: Would I need a some type of `List.Add`?

Comment: Are you sure that someList actually contains what you're looking for?  No typos, no mismatched cases, no extraneous spaces?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Wrong.  You can use `&` with `bool` values as well.  The difference between `&` and `&&` when used on `bool` is that the latter does short circuiting.

Comment: Are you sure the values match exactly?  Could there be differences in case or maybe leading or trailing spaces?   Try debugging the code and inspecting the values to make sure they match exactly.

Comment: @juharr, Yes, I have checked that. I even trimmed the input for the Name, and still no result....

Comment: should `John` and `Technician` be `"John"` and `"Technician"`?  It would not compile unless you had string variables (or fields) with those names.

Comment: Can you prove what you say? Like expanding the `someList` and it's items in the debugger Locals/Watch window and posting a screenshot showing that the famous `John, Technician` is there.

Comment: I am suggesting that these are objects that take string types.

Comment: @DStanley I edited the values to strings, sorry.

Comment: @IvanStoev I apologize I did not run this code, though I have existing code that does similar that does not seem to match the values in the LINQ query and return something to `fullList` , when the list does generate values for `someList`. So, there are values that exist in the `someList` am using in the LINQ that is stored in `fullList`. Also, when I check the count for something like in `fullList` it returns 0, even though `someList` should populate a list. I am using dbcontext with the entity framework to generate data like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope its because of missing "&&"

```
var someList = someDbContext.Items.ToList();    
var fullList = (from item in someList
                where item.Name == data.Name 
                && item.Job == data.Job
                select item).ToList();
```

If `someList` has any value, then `fullList` will contains a value. Check [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bR7IyO) sample code.

Comment: Stranglely, though the it runs with the &&, nothing is in the list still, so still not working.

Comment: Changing `&` to `&&` will make absolutely no difference in the results; it will just save some unnecessary comparisons.

Comment: @JDavila: Is there any value in somelist?

Comment: Yeah, there are values in `someList` in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

data appears to be just a local object. You still need to add it to your data source. Possibly like:

```
someDbContext.Items.Add(data)
```

Comment: I am generating a list from a database, why would I need to add data to  already existing data from the data source?

Answer (score 0):

```
Data data = new Data();
Models.DataModel someDBContext = new Models.DataModel();

data.Name = "John";
data.Job = "Technician";

someDbContext.Items.Add(data);
someDbContext.SaveChanges();   

var fullList = (from item in someDbContext.Items
                    where item.Name == data.Name 
                    && item.Job == data.Job
                    select item).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the scenario doing something as below:

```
Data data = new Data();
Models.DataModel someDBContext = new Models.DataModel();

data.Name = "John";
data.Job = "Technician";

var fullList = from item in someDbContext.Items
                    select item;

foreach (var item in fullList){
       if(item.Name.Trim() == data.Name && item.Job == data.Job)
          {
           someDBContext.Items.Add(item);
          }
}
someDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

For whatever reason, when creating a list with the LINQ query the items would not work with matching using an conditional, `fullList` had to be created using a query and then access individually using the dbcontext.